# How to make a clickable C# Console output line like in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, console, rider

Unity Game Engine has a very useful feature in its console, where you can click on any line in the output, and it will take you to the line of source code that produced it.

For example

`Debug.Log("test");` (line 20 in Test.cs)

will output

`test`

double clicking on test, will bring you back to line 20 in Test.cs in the IDE.

I was wondering, is there some way to do this in normal C# development? I'm using Rider IDE, but I suspect this is some kind of hyperlink rather than something IDE dependent. Although perhaps that's not accurate.

Comment: You might check if that's revealed in Unity's reference code, https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use hyperlink in Unity's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232311/is-there-a-way-to-use-hyperlink-in-unitys-console)

Comment: @mcky no I’m trying to do this OUTSIDE of unity, but borrowing some nice functionality from it.

Comment: @LexLi that was a helpful suggestion. Going to try out some more things and post an answer when I’ve had a chance to polish it off. Thanks

Comment: You can copy stacktrace to the clipboard and call action Analyse Stacktrace in Rider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out pretty well. This piggybacks on Jetbrains IDEs parsing the console, and it creates links to paths. I'm not sure this will work in other IDEs, but it actually works super well for what I wanted.

```
const string ProjectFolder = "MyProject/";
    
public static void Log(string message,
    [CallerMemberName] string callingMethod = "",
    [CallerFilePath] string callingFilePath = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int callingFileLineNumber = 0)
{

    string pathFromProjectFolder = callingFilePath.Split(ProjectFolder).LastOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine($"{message}   {pathFromProjectFolder}:{callingFileLineNumber} ");
}
```

Calling this method produces something like this in the console for Rider. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current Windows Terminal does not support clickable links. However, it is a planned [feature for WT 2.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/terminal-v2-roadmap.md). Read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/7251) for the pull request. You may be able to build their dev branch if you are just doing a project for yourself.

Right now, you can obviously open your ide with arguments but I think that's your only option.

##### Edit:

@LexLi had a great comment [referencing this](https://github.com/TomaszRewak/C-sharp-console-gui-framework) which is a ".NET framework for creating console-based GUI applications". Which brings up a great point that you CAN absolutely listen for clicks yourself.

Comment: I wonder why Windows Terminal is ever needed here. A .NET app can handle clicks itself in console https://github.com/TomaszRewak/C-sharp-console-gui-framework